# generic shared_ptr as member of a class

Tags: c++, templates, shared-ptr

I want to have a shared_ptr as a member of a class, but the type that the shared_ptr manages is different each time and is only known at run time. Is there any way to declare such a member and init it later?

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

Use runtime polymorphism which means define a common base class, say `Base` and declare the common interfaces as virtual functions in it, then derive from it and implement the virtual functions in the derived classes. If you do so, then you can use like this:

```
std::share_ptr<Base> ptr;
//now ptr can store an instance of any derived class from Base
```

Or you could use `boost::any` if it is not possible to define a common base class. If you cannot use Boost, then you can define `any` class yourself. Search for Type Erasure on this site and in google.

The following is a two-pages article on Type Erasure, and you can find an implementation of `boost::any` on the [second page](http://www.artima.com/cppsource/type_erasure2.html) (though not complete):

- [What Type Erasure Can Do About It](http://www.artima.com/cppsource/type_erasure.html)

Comment: Do you mean `std::shared_ptr<Base>`?

Answer (score 1):

If the types are unrelated, you can use something like [`Boost.Any`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/any.html) for this. Otherwise, do what [@Nawaz says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8592473/160206).